# is two inner joins is best for optimization of query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, optimization

i just got a challenge from school optimise this query this is theoretical question

Challenge :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',tableA."date"),'YYYY-MM') AS "date_month",
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (tableB."date" IS NOT NULL) THEN tableB._id ELSE NULL END) AS "tableB.countB",
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (tableC."date" IS NOT NULL) THEN tableC._id ELSE NULL END) AS "tableC.countC"
FROM tableA AS tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB AS tableB ON (DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',tableB."date"))) = (DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',tableA."date")))
LEFT JOIN tableC AS tableC ON (DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',tableC."date"))) = (DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',tableA."date")))
WHERE tableA."date" >= CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('America/Los_Angeles','UTC',DATEADD (month,-17,DATE_TRUNC('month',DATE_TRUNC('day',CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',GETDATE ()))))
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 500;
```

for optimize,  i just remove case statements in above mentioned query i think this will also improve the efficiency of query

```
SELECT    To_char(Convert_timezone ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',tablea."date"),'YYYY-MM') AS "date_month", 
          Count(DISTINCT 
           decode(tableb."date", not null,tableb._id,null)
           AS "tableB.countB",
          Count(DISTINCT 
           decode(tablec."date", not null,tablec._id ,null)
            AS "tableC.countC"  
FROM      tablea AS tablea 
LEFT JOIN tableb AS tableb 
ON        ( 
                    Date (Convert_timezone ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',tableb."date"))) = (Date (Convert_timezone ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',tablea."date")))
LEFT JOIN tablec AS tablec 
ON        ( 
                    Date (Convert_timezone ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',tablec."date"))) = (Date (Convert_timezone ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',tablea."date")))
WHERE     tablea."date" >= convert_timezone ('America/Los_Angeles','UTC',Dateadd (month,-17,Date_trunc('month',Date_trunc('day',Convert_timezone ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',Getdate ())))) group BY 1 ORDER BY 1 DESC limit 500;
```

what you suggest if we remove one left join and merge the statement 
is that fine for optimization

Comment: Please post DDL,DML Of the tables involved and dont post images.Having this info helps others to quickly repro your issue and asnwer better.Below is some sample which might help you understand.  

**--sample data**  
`create table t1
(
id int
)

insert into t1
values
(1),
(2),
(1)
`    
**my current query/what i have tried:**   
`select id,count(*) as cnt from
t1
group by id`  

**my current result:**  
`id cnt
1  2
2  1`

**my expected result:**
`id cnt
1  2
2  1
1  2`

Comment: One quick optimization is to not give an alias to a table, where the alias is exactly the same as the table name. `FROM tableA as tableA` is exactly the same as `FROM tableA`. This simple modification will not make the code any faster, but it will make your brain (and certainly mine!) work a lot faster when reading the code.

Comment: Please tag your post with the proper database product name. You have it tagged as `Oracle` which is certainly not correct (I will remove the `oracle` tag in a moment). In Oracle you can't group by 1 (meaning by the first column), there is no `convert_timezone`, etc. I don't recognize your product but it is definitely not Oracle Database.

Comment: ... or, use a shorter alias that actually makes the SQL shorter and cleaner. This also helps read-ability. Also, format it to separate clauses (Select, From, Join, Where, Order By, Group by, Having, etc. so they are easy to separate and distinguish with the eye. and use indentation consistent with the logical structure that supports, and does not hinder, you ability to separate those sections one from another.

Comment: Take your question with the database you are using.

Comment: IMHO two scalar subqueries could simplify this code. At least, the conditional aggregations would not be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... or, use a shorter alias that actually makes the SQL shorter and cleaner. This also helps read-ability. Also, format it to separate clauses (Select, From, Join, Where, Order By, Group by, Having, etc. so they are easy to separate and distinguish with the eye. and use indentation consistent with the logical structure that supports, and does not hinder, you ability to separate those sections one from another.
Just as an example, here's your first SQL query re formatted, but identical in logical structure to what you posted:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles', a.date),'YYYY-MM') date_month,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (b."date" IS NOT NULL) THEN b._id ELSE NULL END) countB,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (c."date" IS NOT NULL) THEN c._id ELSE NULL END) countC
FROM tableA a   
  LEFT JOIN tableB b 
     ON (DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',b.date))) = 
        (DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',a.date)))
  LEFT JOIN tableC c 
     ON (DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',c.date))) = 
        (DATE (CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles',a.date)))
WHERE a.date >= CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('America/Los_Angeles', 'UTC', 
       DATEADD (month,-17,DATE_TRUNC('month', 
       DATE_TRUNC('day',CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC','America/Los_Angeles', 
                        GETDATE ()))))
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 500;
```

Here is an optimized version

```
SELECT DatePart(month, a.Date-8/24) date_month, 
  sum(case when b.date is Not null then 1 else 0 end) countb,
  sum(case when c.date is Not null then 1 else 0 end) countc,
FROM tableA a    
  LEFT JOIN tableB b 
     ON b.Date = a.Date -- Timezone offsets are not necessary, 
  LEFT JOIN tableC c  
     ON c.date = a.date -- both in same timezone 
WHERE a.date >= DateAdd(hour, 8,
            DATEADD (month,-17,DATE_TRUNC('month', 
             GETDATE () ))
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 500;
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the `_id` columns are unique.  So:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC','America/Los_Angeles', a."date"), 'YYYY-MM') AS date_month,
       SUM(CASE WHEN b."date" IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tableB_countB,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c."date" IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tableC_countC
FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN
     tableB b
     ON DATE(CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles', b."date")) = DATE(CONVERT_TIMEZONE ('UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles', b."date")) LEFT JOIN
     tableC c
      ON DATE(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles', c."date")) = DATE(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles', a."date")
WHERE a."date" >= CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Los_Angeles', 'UTC',
                                   DATEADD(month, -17, DATE_TRUNC('month', DATE_TRUNC('day', CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles', GETDATE ()))
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 500;
```

Then, the date conversions in the `ON` clause don't seem necessary, because the two sides are being converted from the same time zone.  If the values have no time component (as suggested by a name like `date`), then the `DATE()` is not needed either:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles', a."date"), 'YYYY-MM') AS date_month,
       SUM(CASE WHEN b."date" IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tableB_countB,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c."date" IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tableC_countC
FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN
     tableB b
     ON b."date" = b."date" LEFT JOIN
     tableC c
      ON c."date" = a."date"
WHERE a."date" >= CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Los_Angeles', 'UTC',
                                   DATEADD(month, -17, DATE_TRUNC('month', DATE_TRUNC('day', CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles', GETDATE ()))
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 500;
```

The `WHERE` clause is fine.  It can take advantage of an index on `a(date)`.